# How do I release the memory used by objects in my dictionary, or is that not needed?

Tags: c#, dictionary, memory

I created a Class (simplified version below):

```
public class UsbDevice
{
    public UsbDevice()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"UsbDevice constructor called");
    }

    ~UsbDevice()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"UsbDevice destructor called");
    }
}
```

I use a dictionary to keep a list of all my UsbDevices.

```
Dictionary<string, UsbDevice> _devices = new Dictionary<string, UsbDevice>();

UsbDevice usbDevice = new UsbDevice();
_devices.Add("Path of the device", usbDevice);
```

When I don't need the UsbDevice any longer, I remove it from the dictionary.

```
_devices.Remove("Path of the device");
```

(I omit all checks if device exists for simplicity)

When I remove the UsbDevice, I see that the destructor is not called. This is only done when the application closes. So it means that the UsbDevice object still exists somewhere in memory, right? I understand that the "Remove" method of the Dictionary doesn't remove the UsbDevice from memory, because the dictionary doesn't know if the UsbDevice might be used (referenced) somewhere else in the code.

How can I get rid of all memory associated with UsbDevice? If I don't get rid of that memory, then add/remove cycles will increase memory usage because of all unused UsbDevices, right? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Have a look at the [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

Comment: C# not so basics: when finalizers are called

Comment: C# does *not* have destructors. It borrows the syntax from C++ (unfortunately, since it causes unnecessary confusion), but these are called finalizers. The distinction is important; the vast majority of classes do not need finalizers, save for a few select low-level wrappers around unmanaged resources (and most of those classes have already been written and are part of the framework). All the rest can use `IDisposable` and `using`, if they need deterministic cleanup of things other than memory.

Comment: @knittl Thanks! That helped a lot indeed!

Answer (score 1):

1. It is better to let CLR decide when to free your memory
2. If you really need to free your memory now - you can use GC.Collect(); This method will consume resources, that's why it is not recommended to use it manually.
3. ~UsbDevice() is not a destructor. This is finalizer. When the Garbage collector finds out that this object can be removed - it checks if there is a finalizer for it. If not - it just removes the object. If yes - then the object will be putted in special queue where there are all the objects, which have finalizer. At some point in time the finalizer will be called, but object still seats in the memory. When the GC makes another iteration - it will see that there is a finalizer, which was already executed - object can be removed from the memory. That's why it is not the good practise to use finalizer.
4. If you want to free some unmanaged resources and you know exactly when this should happen - have a look to IDisposable.

Comment: I used GC.Collect() for testing, and then see my finalizers being called (at least, the ones of the UsbDevices that are removed from my dictionary). So I assume that this shows that in case the GC decides that a collection is needed, the memory of unused UsbDevices will be freed up. That definitely gives me peace of mind, and I learned a lot!

Comment: And I don't need finalizers indeed - I just used them to check when memory would be freed up. All is clear now!